# Problema con react-pdf al tratar de correr el proyecto sale Failed to load PDF file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jspdf

He tratado de correr el siguiente código pero no he logrado leer el PDF con el CLI de react, espero me puedan ayudar, dejo la información:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';
// import 'react-pdf/dist/Page/AnnotationLayer.css';
class Pdf extends Component {
  state = {
    numPages: null,
    pageNumber: 1,
    file: '../../public/test.pdf'
  }

  onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }) => {
    this.setState({ numPages });
  }

  render() {
    const { pageNumber, numPages, file } = this.state;

    return (
        <Document
          file={file}
        />
    );
  }
}
export default Pdf;
```

**Este es mi package.json:**

```
{
 "name": "leer-pdf",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "react": "^16.5.2",
   "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
   "react-pdf": "3.0.5",
   "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
 },
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
  "devDependencies": {
   "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2"
  }
}
```

**Lo que me saca en la pagina y el network**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El error que genera:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es este `file="test.pdf"`, trata de cambiarlo a `file="./test.pdf"`.

Si tu tienes una estructura de archivos así:

- src

  - App.js
  - components

    - Pdf.js
    - test.pdf
- public

  - bundle.js

Entonces necesitas mover `test.pdf` a la carpeta `public` así:

- src

  - App.js
  - components

    - Pdf.js
- public

  - bundle.js
  - test.pdf

Porque cuando tu código compilado es ejecutado desde `public/bundle.js` y `bundle.js` no conoce como llegar a `src/components/test.pdf` en el sistema de archivos.

También puede haber una diferencia entre el entorno de producción/desarrollo si está utilizando `webpack` y`webpack-dev-server`

Mira el ejemplo de `react-pdf`. Tiene estructura de archivo plano. Esa es la razón por la que funciona.

[image]

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48589400/10158153)

También podrías declarar tu archivo en el `state` así:

```
class Pdf extends Component {
 state = {
  numPages: null,
  pageNumber: 1,
  file: './test.pdf'
}
```

y llamarlo en el render así:

```
render() {
   const { pageNumber, numPages, file } = this.state;

    return (
      <Document
        file={file}
      />
  );
}
```

Comment: David muchas gracias por la respuesta pase el archivo a la carpeta public como dijiste quedando entonces con la siguiente ruta de lectura:
state = {
    numPages: null,
    pageNumber: 1,
    file: '../../public/test.pdf'
  }
Sin embargo sigue sin funcionar. Saca el mismo error.

Comment: Lo otro es que estoy trabajando con el CLI de react, no se si se pueda modificar el webpack desde ahí, subo el código del webpack que tiene por defecto?

Answer (score 0):

La solución a este problema por si alguien tiene este mismo inconveniente es:

1. Has un clone Sample desde la siguiente ruta y estudia el codigo del sample:

   - https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/tree/master/sample/parcel.
   - Te paras en el cmd o terminal y instalas las dependencias yarn     install o npm install.
   - lo corres con yarn start o npm start.

     2. Mis errores fueron los siguiente:
   - Los archivos que se importan img o pdf, para cargarlos en los componentes, se colocan dentro de la carpeta SRC no fuera. Y se importan de esta forma

     import sample from './sample.pdf';

-Se debe de implementar un metodo para el componente  en el evento onLoadSuccess, el metodo se encarga de contar el numero de las  paginas

- Se tiene q implementar un script que se pasa como propiedad hijo que permita recorrer la cantidad de paginas que tenga el PDF al componente  algo como esto:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';
import test from './sample.pdf';
// import 'react-pdf/dist/Page/AnnotationLayer.css';

const options = {
  cMapUrl: 'cmaps/',
  cMapPacked: true,
};
class Pdf extends Component {
  state = {
    numPages: null,
    pageNumber: 1,
    file: test
  }

  onDocumentLoadSuccess = ({ numPages }) => {
    this.setState({ numPages });
  }

  render() {
    const { pageNumber, numPages, file } = this.state;

    return (
      <Document file={file} onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoadSuccess} options={options}>
        {
                Array.from(
                  new Array(numPages),
                  (el, index) => (
                    <Page
                      key={`page_${index + 1}`}
                      pageNumber={index + 1}
                    />
                  ),
                )
        }
      </Document>
    );
  }
}
export default Pdf;
```

SI TIENEN OTRO COMPONENTE PARA RECOMENDAR QUE TENGA QUE VER CON PDF LES AGRADECERÍA MUCHO, SI SABEN DE FUNCIONALIDADES COMO ZOOM U OTRAS QUE SE LE PUEDE APLICAR A ESTE COMPONENTE LES AGRADECERÍA